# Upgrading Uboot to support PCIe switch, PCIe to PCI bridge, POE

Tags: embedded-linux, bootloader, u-boot

What changes will be required (if any) in the UBoot bootloader if the following h/w is added to an existing arm based board.
a) PCIe switch
b) PCIe to PCI bridge
c) Power over ethernet

Comment: I wouldn't think PoE would require any software changes.

Comment: The original board has 1000BASE-T ethernet ports. We have two options for the POE
A) use phantom power technique to maintain gigabit support
B) downgrade to 100 BASE-TX
Ur answer seems reasonable about the case A) what about case B) ?